# GitHub - Change Misspelled Commit Message

Tags: github

Is there a way in GitHub to change a commit message if I've committed with a message that has a typo or something dumb written in it?

I know you can do the ammend commit thing (which replaces the previous commit) from the CLI, but is there a way to just edit the commit message from the GitHub.com site interface?

Comment: I think you meant to say *ammend* instead of *append*.

Comment: Why don't you just want to do this from the command line?

Comment: Lets just pretend I'm not a big fan of the command line...or that I'm asking for a friend. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the problem commit is more than one commit ago, you have to fall back to interactive rebase. For example, if you notice a misspelling three commits ago, you would type something like this:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

Then rebase would open up your default editor with a view that looked something like this:

```
pick c5052cb Updated the workshop instructions
pick 6d6cd60 Upgraded to the plugin 0.6.1
pick c6d0921 Upgraded wrapper to Gradle 1.2
pick 7a111da Upgraded to 0.7 of the Liquibase Gradle Plugin.

# Rebase 097e6b2..7a111da onto 097e6b2
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
```

You'd want to edit the third line (the one referring to commit `c6d0921`) to start with the word "reword" instead of "pick." Once you save and exit from the editor, you'll find yourself right back in the editor with that commit's message in front of you. Correct your misspelling, save and exit, and all is well.

Note that doing this or doing a `commit --ammend` is dangerous business if you've already pushed these commits to an upstream repo. This is why there's no way to do this on GitHub.com directly. If you want to change commits you've already pushed, that's a separate matter entirely. :)

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a way to do it directly on the site.

You could:

```
git commit --amend
git push --force origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the main reasons we don't want to allow people to do this on the site is because it'd change the entire structure of the commit (basically just think of this as changing the commit hash). This isn't a problem when it's only you, but for the sake of a community of people working with you, this is a problem because no one else will have that commit, and when they try to pull they run into issues.

This is the same as doing the ammend on the command line AFTER you've pushed, then force pushing to github.com. Usually a major no-no for workflows unless you take care with a lot of extra communication.